# Sort os.listdir files Python

Tags: python, file, sorting, python-2.7, io

If have downloaded several years of data stored in files with the following naming convention, year_day.dat. For example, the file named 2014_1.dat has the data for January 1, 2014.  I need to read these data files ordered by day, 2014_1.dat, 2014_2.dat, 2014_3.dat until the end of the year. In the folder they are listed in that ordered BUT when I create a list of the files in the directory they are reordered 2014_1.dat, 2014_10.dat, 2014_100.dat, 2014_101.dat...2014.199.dat, 2014_2.dat.
I think I need to use a sort function but how do I force it to sort the listed files by day so I can continue processing them? 
Here's the code so far:

```
import sys, os, gzip, fileinput, collections
# Set the input/output directories
wrkDir = "C:/LJBTemp"
inDir = wrkDir + "/Input"
outDir = wrkDir + "/Output"
# here we go
inList = os.listdir(inDir)  # List all the files in the 'Input' directory
print inList  #print to screen reveals 2014_1.dat.gz followed by 2014_10.dat.gz NOT    2014_2.dat.gz HELP
d = {}
for fileName in inList:     # Step through each input file 
    readFileName = inDir + "/" + fileName

    with gzip.open(readFileName, 'r') as f: #call built in utility to unzip file for reading
      for line in f:
          city, long, lat, elev, temp = line.split() #create dictionary
          d.setdefault(city, []).append(temp) #populate dictionary with city and associated temp data from each input file
          collections.OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda d: d[0])) # QUESTION? why doesn't this work
          #now collect and write to output file
outFileName = outDir + "/" + "1981_maxT.dat" #create output file in output directory with .dat extension
with open(outFileName, 'w') as f:
     for city, values in d.items():
        f.write('{} {}\n'.format(city, ' '.join(values)))

print "All done!!"
raw_input("Press <enter>") # this keeps the window open until you press "enter"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind using third party libraries, you can use the [natsort](https://github.com/SethMMorton/natsort) library, which was designed for exactly this situation.

```
import natsort
inList = natsort.natsorted(os.listdir(inDir))
```

This should take care of all the numerical sorting without having to worry about the details.

You can also use the `ns.PATH` option to make the sorting algorithm path-aware:

```
from natsort import natsorted, ns
inList = natsorted(os.listdir(inDir), alg=ns.PATH)
```

---

Full disclosure, I am the `natsort` author.

Comment: You are a hero!

Answer (score 0):

Try this if all of your files start with '2014_':

```
sorted(inList, key = lambda k: int(k.split('_')[1].split('.')[0]))
```

Otherwise take advantage of tuple comparison, sorting by the year first then the second part of your file name.

```
sorted(inList, key = lambda k: (int(k.split('_')[0]), int(k.split('_')[1].split('.')[0])))
```

Comment: thank you for your help. I used third party sort library natsort for this application but will try your suggestion for another application.

Answer (score 0):

`dict.items` returns a list of `(key, item)` pair.

the key function is only using the first element (`d[0]` => `key` => city).

There's another problem: `sorted` returns a new copy of the list sorted, and does not sort the list inplace. Also the `OrderedDict` object is created and not assigned anywhere; Actually, you don't need to sort each time you append the item to the list.

Removing the `... sorted ...` line, and replacing following line:

```
with open(outFileName, 'w') as f:
     for city, values in d.items():
        f.write('{} {}\n'.format(city, ' '.join(values)))
```

with following will solve your problem:

```
with open(outFileName, 'w') as f:
     for city, values in d.items():
        values.sort(key=lambda fn: map(int, os.path.splitext(fn)[0].split('_')))
        f.write('{} {}\n'.format(city, ' '.join(values)))
```

BTW, instead of manually joining hard-coded separator `/`, use [`os.path.join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join):

```
inDir + "/" + fileName

 =>

os.path.join(inDir, fileName)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. The values.sort solution does sort the values in the printed output from largest to smallest. But what I'm trying to do is reproduce an output format so that each time the code is run the city order remains the same. I have 30 years of input data and need the output to be standardized for the next phase on coding.

Comment: @MapleMatrix, If you want to also sort by city, replace `for city, values in d.items():` with `for city, values in sorted(d.items()):`.