# How to write a csv file with 2 columns consisting of path+filenames from two different folders in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, csv, export-to-csv

I want to create a csv file with 2 columns consisting of the path + filename concatenated. The first column should contain the path+filenames of Folder1 and 2nd column should contain the path+filenames of Folder 2.
Both the operation should be in parallel.

Col1                   Col2
data/RGB/image_6_1.png, data/rear/depth/image_6_0.png
The list has more images.

The name ordering should be similar.May be a zip function would help?

Comment: Please paste the code in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python's [`izip_longest()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html?highlight=izip_longest#itertools.izip_longest) is useful in this situation. It will give you elements from both lists one at a time. When one list is exhausted (i.e. there are more files in one folder that the other), it will return `None` by default for the empty element. With this you can then pass it a list of files from each folder and write them to your CSV file using Python's `csv` library as follows:

```
from itertools import izip_longest
import os
import csv


def numbers(x):
    s = x.split('_')
    output = []

    for v in s:
        try:
            output.append(int(v))
        except ValueError as e:
            output.append(v)

    return output   

folder1 = r"/my/folder1"
folder2 = r"/my/folder2"

with open('output.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)

    for f1, f2 in izip_longest(sorted(os.listdir(folder1), key=numbers), sorted(os.listdir(folder2), key=numbers)):
        p1 = p2 = ''

        if f1:
            p1 = os.path.join(folder1, f1)
        if f2:
            p2 = os.path.join(folder2, f2)

        csv_output.writerow([p1, p2])
```

`os.path.join()` is used to safely concatenate path components together.

As your filenames contain numbers, to sort numerically you will need to split each name and convert the resulting list of string into integers where possible. This would then let it sort numerically.

This example is designed for Python 2.x

---

Alternatively, if rather than sorting it using your own logic, you could use a library such as `natsorted`:

```
from itertools import izip_longest
from natsort import natsorted
import os
import csv


folder1 = r"/my/folder1"
folder2 = r"/my/folder2"

with open('output.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)

    for f1, f2 in izip_longest(natsorted(os.listdir(folder1)), natsorted(os.listdir(folder2))):
        p1 = p2 = ''

        if f1:
            p1 = os.path.join(folder1, f1)
        if f2:
            p2 = os.path.join(folder2, f2)

        csv_output.writerow([p1, p2])
```

This can be installed using:

```
pip install natsorted
```

Comment: Thanks Martin it works. But a small issue.
The name order is not maintained in this code. 
data/RGB/image_6_1.png, data/rear/depth/image_6_0.png 
Obtaining a csv of 
data/RGB/image_55_1.png, data/rear/depth/image22_0.png
Both should correspond or needs to be sorted.

Comment: The output from `listdir()` can be sorted before passing it to `izip_longest()`. In your case though, your names will need additional effort to be sorted numerically rather than alphabetically.

Comment: Any suggestions as to how to proceed with it. If I do not sort it the generation of the csv file would not be useful at all.

Comment: I have updated the script to show you two solutions. Firstly I split your filenames on the `_` character, convert each part to a number and sort based on the resulting list. Secondly I have shown how a library called `natsorted` could be used to do the same thing.

Comment: I found the solution here. [Sort os.listdir files Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21898560/sort-os-listdir-files-python)

Thanks for editing the script though.

Comment: A small issue though the script would throw up an error if I use it in Python3.x
I used `zip_longest()` instead of `izip_longest()`.

Comment: You would also need to use `open('output.csv', 'w', newline='')`

Comment: You are welcome! Don't forget to click on the grey tick under the up/down buttons to accept the answer as the accepted solution.